# C++ Void double pointer interference with another

Tags: c++, memory, void-pointers, double-pointer

I am trying to do a project that involves overloading new and delete. I am storing an array of void pointers (pointers to random memory that is allocated) in a double void pointer. Of course, this array will need to be resized to account for further void pointers that come in.

This is the intialization of the array, allocArraySize(int) is set to 4.

`void** allocArray = (void**) calloc ( allocArraySize, sizeof(void*) );`

Setting all values to nullptr..

`for(int i=0; i<allocArraySize; i++){ *(allocArray + i*sizeof(void*)) = nullptr; }`

However, when trying to resize the array, I noticed that my original array of void pointers is modified when I create a new temporary array(temp) to store them in.

```
// PRINTS THE ORIGINAL ARRAY 
for(int i=0; i<allocArraySize; i++){std::cout<<i<<" = "<<*( allocArray + i*sizeof(void*))<<"\n";}

void** tempArray = (void**)calloc(allocArraySize, sizeof(void*));

// PRINTS THE ORIGINAL ARRAY 
for(int i=0; i<allocArraySize; i++){std::cout<<i<<" = "<<*( allocArray + i*sizeof(void*))<<"\n";}`
```

Notice, I am not even putting the array values in the temp array yet and I am still getting this problem. Why is that? why is this random value being assigned to this spot when it is indeed initialized? How is this one new temp array variable messing with my array?

NOTE: This is basically the complete code. Only thing missing is a main function, iostream, and the declaration for allocArraySize. Yes, WELL aware that I am not freeing these poor double pointers. I just wanted to create the problem in simplest terms possible.

Comment: why C++ code would use calloc...

Comment: Fyi. the loop to set all pointers to `nullptr` is pointleess. They're already null after th zero-fill from `calloc`. And your `sizeof` operations during printing shouldn't be there. Pointer arithmetic will handle the offsets for you already.

Comment: `allocArray + i*sizeof(void*)` is going to go past the end of your array when `i` is bigger than 0, given `arrayAllocSize` is 4.

Comment: Please add an input and the output of the input, if possible also the expected output

Comment: This is all technically undefined behaviour, you should use containers such as `vector` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sizeof multiplier shouldn't be there:

```
*(allocArray + i*sizeof(void*))
//              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this shouldn't be here
```

`void**` is strongly typed. It participates in proper offset calculation via pointer arithmetic. There is no need here for sizeof offset calculations. That loop, which appears to be crafted to dump the pointer values in the sequence, should therefore be:

```
for(int i=0; i<allocArraySize; i++)
{
    std::cout<< i << " = " << allocArray[i] << "\n";
}
```

Comment: All pointer arithmetic "participates in proper offset calculation",  except for ill-formed/UB code obviously.

Comment: @M.M was there a specific reason you excised the  "via pointer arithmetic" part of that surgical citation? Just trying to understand whatever you seem to think I missed.

Comment: It seems you were implying that there are other situations that do not perform "proper offset calculation" or where sizeof offset calculations are required

Answer (score 1):

You are indexing the pointers incorrectly `i * sizeof(void*)` rather than `i`.

```cpp
for(int i=0; i<allocArraySize; i++){ allocArray[i] = nullptr; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,  you rather shouldn't use calloc in C++ code. Especially if you program uses both new expression and calloc\malloc, it may lead to to UB due to mismatching deletors.

`allocArraySize` got type `void**` , so it's pointer to pointer. Result of expression `*allocArraySize` got same sizeof as  `void*` or `uintptr_t` type. Arithmetic with pointers automatically increment pointer by amount  required to point at next object of same type.

C++ way to write it doesn't even require such arcane knowledge either, all you should do is to use a new expression and list-initialize it with empty list to get same effect as `calloc` does in C.

```
void** allocArray = ::new void*[allocArraySize] {};

for(int i = 0; i < allocArraySize; ++i)
{
     std::cout<< i << " = " << allocArray[i] << "\n";
}
```

When using new/delete from within of overloaded one, it's essential to use `::` or it would lead to  infinite recursion.

`allocArray[i]` is an equivalent of `*(allocArray + i)`

Overloading new\delete aside. But truly C++ way to do that is to avoid naked pointers and use containers if possible. New\delete might be wrappers around usage of some memory pool class.

```
// do we really need a vector of pointers?
auto allocArray = std::vector<void*>(allocArraySize, nullptr);

int i = 0;
for( auto &v : allocArray )
    std::cout<< (i++) << " = " << v << "\n";
```

In C++20 range-based for loop becomes more contained thanks to init-statement

```
for(int i = 0; auto &v : allocArray )
      std::cout<< (i++) << " = " << v << "\n";
```

Comment: If you are overloading new & delete, and are using a std::vector to do it, you're doing it wrong.